# Trouble showing images in other pages than Home (wordpress/html/css)

Tags: php, html, image, wordpress, visibility

Hi I have a small website im doing for a customer and I have used a html/css-site and transferred it to wordpress by using blank theme. So far so good, have a look at energyshop.se if u want and in startpage the top two images are shown, but not udner the rest of the tabs - why? I add the images in the header.php so it should find them on all tabs...?

**//header.php**

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="container">
```

```
    <div id="header" onclick="location.href='http://www.energyshop.se/';" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
        <div class="description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>
    </div>
<div id="main_menu">
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using relative paths. When creating a WordPress theme and you want to load resources from your theme, you should use absolute paths. There are two template tags that make this easy for you: `get_bloginfo()` and `bloginfo()`. The first one returns the value, and the second one echoes the value(that you request via the first argument passed to the function).

So in order to display an image, you should have:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/icon_en_global.png" alt="English.png">
```

This will always result in this(for your site):

```
<img src="http://energyshop.se/wp-content/themes/blank/images/icon_en_global.png" alt="English.png">
```

So simply replace all `wp-content/themes/blank` with `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>`.

Comment: Ok ill try this rightaway, but when you say all, do you mean the content too (which i pasted) into wordpress pages or only in this header? What I mean will the relative paths mess up for me in the content images as well?

Comment: Btw, your awesome :D it worked as a charm, Ill green your post!

Comment: If you insert links/images through the WordPress rich text editor, the paths should already be absolute in your pages/posts content - so you won't have to change those :)